# Highchart js with data from db Yii2

Tags: php, highcharts, yii2

I tried to put my data from database to 'series' of highchart via data provider. I use [this](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts) widget. Now chart is rendered, but i got another problem with categories, as you can see on printscreen.

[`index.php`](https://hastebin.com/mubasunaba.xml)

I guess `print_r` looks good:

[image]

how can I solve the problem?

Comment: - use echo json_encode($urData);   instead of print_r.

Comment: Edited. I chanched prtscr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of reading posts i decided to come back to documention, and i found the solution of my problem `https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts/blob/master/doc/examples/series-data-helper.md`

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use miloschuman\highcharts\Highcharts;
use miloschuman\highcharts\SeriesDataHelper;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$data = $provider->getModels();
$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider(['allModels' => $data]);

?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 strategy_bar">
        <?php 
            echo Highcharts::widget([
                'options' => [
                    'title' => ['text' => 'Basic Example'],
                    'yAxis' => [
                        ['title' => [
                            'text' => 'OHLC'
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    'series' => [
                        [
                            'type' => 'column',
                            'name' => new SeriesDataHelper($dataProvider, ['strategy_title']),
                            'data' => new SeriesDataHelper($dataProvider, ['strategy_current_money:int']),
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pASHM.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $provider->getModels();

$barData = array();
$xAxis = array();

if(is_array($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $barData[] = [
            'name' => $row['strategy_title'],
            'data' => [(float) $row['strategy_current_money']]
        ];  
        $xAxis[] = [
            'categories' => $row['strategy_title'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Try like this. I am not sure if I understand well but trying to help. I solved you first problem with []. For other problems you must be more specific.

Comment: Yes, it`s worked, now i have rendered my data column, but i have another problem with xAxis. Edited question.

Comment: $xAxis[] = [
                'categories' => $strategy_current_money
            ];

Replace with this... $strategy is index in foreach loop, a supose that you dont want to set that on xAxis.. I have edit answer, so you can copy to try..

Comment: No, I want the 'strategy_title, which I take in the ArrayHelper::map() to be the X axis. If i replace $strategy to $strategy_current_money, i`ve got this https://imgur.com/11Dd2Zr

As you can see, the only first number is render. Why?

Comment: I see you are new to yii2. You shouldnt use ArrayHelper then. It is used mostly when you want to fill dropdownlist or something like that. In you case I will use data in foreach loop. I will edit answer becouse I am not sure that you understand me..